# Ambiguous reference to member data task(with: completionHandler:)

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurlsession

Why I'm I getting an issue with my completion handler and how can I fix this?

```
func loadImageusingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String) {

    self.image = nil
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    let url = NSURL(string : urlString)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!,
                               completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if let currImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                imageCache.setObject(currImage, forKey: urlString)
                self.image = currImage
            }

            //cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
        })

    }).resume()

}
```

Comment: It is confused by use of `NSURL`. Use `URL` nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
let url = URL(string : urlString)
```

Also you may get an error "Value of optional type 'Data?' not unwrapped", so you should write:

```
if let currImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
     imageCache.setObject(currImage, forKey: urlString)
     self.image = currImage
}
```